# Pass return from JQuery Function to Another Function?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am working on a form validator and when I call the function submitcheck at the bottom the if condition isn't being met and the `$("#send").button("enable");` isn't firing.  I've confirmed without the if statement that the function does get called and if `$("#send").button("enable");` fires it works as intended. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    function submitcheck() {
        if (firstnamecheck() & lastnamecheck() & phonenumbercheck() & emailaddresscheck() & customermessagecheck() == true) {
            $("#send").button("enable");
        }
    }

    $(".email").click(function() {
        $("#email-form").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#first-name").keyup(function(firstnamecheck) {
        if ($("#first-name").val().length >= 2) {
            $("#first-name-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#first-name").val().length < 2) {
            $("#first-name-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#last-name").keyup(function(lastnamecheck) {
        if ($("#last-name").val().length >= 2) {
            $("#last-name-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#last-name").val().length < 2) {
            $("#last-name-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#area-code, #phone-prefix, #phone-postfix").keyup(function(phonenumbercheck) {
        if ((($("#area-code").val().length == 3) && ($("#phone-prefix").val().length == 3) && ($("#phone-postfix").val().length == 4))) {
            $("#phone-number-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ((($("#area-code").val().length < 3) && ($("#phone-prefix").val().length < 3) && ($("#phone-postfix").val().length < 4))) {
            $("#phone-number-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#email-address").keyup(function(emailaddresscheck) {
        if ($("#email-address").val().length >= 6) {
            $("#email-address-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#email-address").val().length <= 5) {
            $("#email-address-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#customer-message").keyup(function(customermessagecheck) {
        if ($("#customer-message").val().length >= 10) {
            $("#customer-message-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#customer-message").val().length <= 9) {
            $("#customer-message-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#customer-message").keyup(submitcheck);
```

OK thanks to you guys I got it figured out. I rewrote the script so it has separate handler functions and seperate activators.  The following DOES work:

```
    function submitcheck() {
        if (firstnamecheck() && lastnamecheck() && phonenumbercheck() && emailaddresscheck() && customermessagecheck() === true) {
            $("#send").button("enable");
        }
    }

    function firstnamecheck() {
        if ($("#first-name").val().length >= 2) {
            $("#first-name-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#first-name").val().length < 2) {
            $("#first-name-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function lastnamecheck() {
        if ($("#last-name").val().length >= 2) {
            $("#last-name-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#last-name").val().length < 2) {
            $("#last-name-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function phonenumbercheck() {
        if ((($("#area-code").val().length == 3) && ($("#phone-prefix").val().length == 3) && ($("#phone-postfix").val().length == 4))) {
            $("#phone-number-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ((($("#area-code").val().length < 3) && ($("#phone-prefix").val().length < 3) && ($("#phone-postfix").val().length < 4))) {
            $("#phone-number-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function emailaddresscheck() {
        if ($("#email-address").val().length >= 6) {
            $("#email-address-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#email-address").val().length <= 5) {
            $("#email-address-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function customermessagecheck() {
        if ($("#customer-message").val().length >= 10) {
            $("#customer-message-check").fadeIn(100);
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#customer-message").val().length <= 9) {
            $("#customer-message-check").fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(".email").click(function() {
        $("#email-form").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#first-name").keyup(firstnamecheck);
    $("#last-name").keyup(lastnamecheck);
    $("#area-code, #phone-prefix, #phone-postfix").keyup(phonenumbercheck);
    $("#email-address").keyup(emailaddresscheck);
    $("#customer-message").keyup(customermessagecheck);

    $("#customer-message").keyup(submitcheck);
```

Comment: You're using `&` instead of `&&` ...

Comment: Please don't tag questions with plugins you're not using.  Removed superflous tags.

Comment: @Pointy: I tried it both ways. Makes no difference.

Comment: @Sparky: So sorry, didn't realize.

Comment: `$("#customer-message").keyup(function(customermessagecheck) {` is **not** creating a function called `customermessagecheck`. Just use `function customermessagecheck()` and so on.

Comment: Where are all those check functions declared?

Comment: So Juhana is right it would seem. Calling them functions doesn't declare them as such after all.  I'd need to rewrite this so all the functions get called at the bottom such as submit check is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and if it works just do the same for every function you have.

```
function submitcheck() {
    if (firstnamecheck() && lastnamecheck() 
         && phonenumbercheck() && emailaddresscheck() 
         && customermessagecheck() === true) {
        $("#send").button("enable");
    }
}

$(".email").click(function() {
    $("#email-form").dialog("open");
});

function firstnamecheck() {
    if ($("#first-name").val().length >= 2) {
        $("#first-name-check").fadeIn(100);
        return true;
    }
    else if ($("#first-name").val().length < 2) {
        $("#first-name-check").fadeOut(100);
        return false;
    }
}

$("#first-name").keyup(firstnamecheck);

$("#customer-message").keyup(submitcheck);
```

Comment: It does!  I posted my solution above!  Thank you so much @NunoCarmo and others!

Comment: @aguyfromhere you really should use `&&` and not `&` - they're not the same. They *appear* to be the same in some situations, but they're not.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this:

```
firstnamecheck() == true & lastnamecheck() == true & phonenumbercheck() == true & emailaddresscheck() == true & customermessagecheck() == true
```

instead of

```
firstnamecheck() & lastnamecheck() & phonenumbercheck() & emailaddresscheck() & customermessagecheck() == true
```

Comment: when you want to compare to true its better to use `===`

Comment: @aguyfromhere: i can't see any meaning in using customermessagecheck() == true inside submitcheck() method. either use '== true' with each check or remove it.